# How to get total by COUNT(*) and a Quantity column

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql

I'm needing to count the total number of elevations that a project contains.

I'm able to get the total number of elevation types by the code below.

```
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Storefront.Elevation e WHERE e.ProjectID = p.ID)'Elevations'
```

But I'm faced with a situation where an elevation for a project can have more than one of that specific elevation. So, a project can have 1 -n elevations, but a elevation can now have 1-n of it's specific type. So if a project has 3 elevations and one of the elevation types has 5 of itself then the project would now have 7 elevations and not 3 because one of the project elevations has 5 of its type.

**Here is what I've tried but I get this error:**

```
   (SELECT COUNT(*) * e.Quantity FROM Storefront.Elevation e WHERE e.ProjectID = p.ID)'Elevations'
```

-Error

```
 Column 'Storefront.Elevation.Quantity' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

I understand the error I just need to know how to correct write this tsql.

Comment: put a `comma` between count(*) and * and e.Quantity

Comment: Please show your table schema and sample data.

Comment: And what is p in p.ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you have a Quantity column against each elevation, why not just sum them?

```
select sum(e.Quantity)
from Storefront.Elevation e
where e.ProjectID = p.ID
```